# How to handle enqueuing new object to circular queue that is full?

Tags: c, stack, queue

I have a circular array that will automatically double it's size when full.
However, I'm not sure how to handle the enqueuing of a new object after doubling the array size.

Can anyone let me know what's the logic to go through?
[image]

Comment: If you've successfully doubled the queue size (while preserving the existing elements), then adding an element should be no different than it was before it was full.

Comment: How would the program know that Rear is at 5th position in the array, and Rear-1 is actually at  2nd position?

Comment: I'm guessing REAR is the input end of the queue and FRONT is the output end? Then after increasing the size of the array, you would need to move the elements between FRONT end and the old size up by the difference between the new and old sizes, and increase the FRONT position by the same amount. Then there is room at the REAR end for the new object.

Comment: @REDBEAN This question has nothing to do with adding a new element.  The only issue in this question is how to enlarge the queue, which is what the question title really should be.  Just draw an example and work out the details.  You know where the front and the rear are.  All of the elements between them need to remain consecutive in the new, larger queue, with the gap on the other side.  It should be simple.